# iOS tableview reload error

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I added some items to list and called [tableView reloadData];

The tableView position is changed.
What is problem?

https://youtu.be/N_LtoJLrsxE

---- added ----

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if([dataCenter.newsList count] > 0){
        return [dataCenter.newsList count];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if((((indexPath.row + 1) - 5) % 10) == 0 && indexPath.row >= 4){
        return 150;
    }
    else if(((indexPath.row + 1) % 5) == 0){
        return 95;
    }
    return 90;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NewsInTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsInTableViewCell"];



    return cell;
}

- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    if(_tableNews.contentOffset.y + _tableNews.frame.size.height == _tableNews.contentSize.height){
        [self requestDataByPage:(int)[dataCenter.newsList count]];
    }
}
```

This is reloadData after calling and adding data.

```
    - (void) requestDataByPage:(int)start{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                            ------calling data and adding-----
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                [_tableNews reloadData];
                            });
                        });
        }
```

Comment: try setting the background colour of that tableview to blue and tableviewCell to red. and then update your question with new screenshots to get the idea behind the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please add Autolayout constraints on reloading the tableview on main thread .

dispatch.async.main{

self.tableview.reloadData()
}

Comment: And what kind of Autolayout constraints do I add?

Comment: tablie constraint for leading , trailing , top and bottom  with respect to superview

Comment: I tried to add some autolayouts. but same situation. Is there the other way to solve?

Answer (score -1):

call:`self.tableView.reloadData()` without [].

If this doesn't solve your problem, give us a bit example code of your project please.

Comment: Sorry, haven't recognised that he's talking about Obj-C.